# ORM and doing correct OOP

Tags: sql, database, oop, activerecord, orm

Often web application have a database. Let say in this database there is for  a table "user" . What I see often is that the developer creates a ORM class to get the data out of the database.  "user" class for example is just a container for data from the database.

That's not what I do. "user" is a encapsulation of the behavior of a user. All code that does something with the user is inside the "user" class. ORM is added because the data is often stored in the database.  I always  define 2 classes: A "users"/"userlist" class (collection of users) and a user (individual user).  The "users"/"userlist" class also representing the table and "user" representing the individual records (for example checking of the password is correct).

What I have noticed that many ORM (like ActiveRecord) system don't make the distinction between table and individual record.  There is just one class "user".

My question is as follows:

- Are there any ORM systems which makes a distinction between table and record (like the users/user in above example)
- How do you use ORM, only for accessing data from database or for real oop.
- If a ORM doesn't make distinction between table and record, where do you place code which processes multiple records
- What do you think is a good way to combine oop and ORM?

Answer (score 0):

An ORM class represents a single record and the entirety of those records represents the table. I don't think there is a need for a class that represents the table. What you commonly have in edition to the individual records is a service (e.g. UserService) that deals with operations on multiple objects.

Comment: What do you exactly mean  with service ?

Comment: A service is a class that provides operations regarding a Single topic. A UserService for example would probably handle registrations, logins, list all users and other things that are done with users. The service is often a single instance of the class shared throughout the program. Often injection is used to pass the service to the class (Controller) that uses it.